# Как можно сделать из объекта массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать из объекта с ключами которые являются объектами, массив объектов?
из апишки приходит не массив с объекстами, а объект с ключами которые являются объектами. Примерный вид вот такой:

```
{
 key1: {
 },
 key2: {
 }
}
```

пытаюсь сделать из него массив, примерно вот такого типа:

```
[{тут ключи key1}, {тут ключи key2}]
```

Comment: `пытаюсь сделать из него массив` покажите как пытаетесь.

Comment: [.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятен тип данных, скорей я не уверен на 100% что это так, но по структуре это JSON.
Входные данные:

```js
// входные данные

var a = {
  key1: {},
  key2: {}
}

// что можно сделать
// получить все ключи
console.log(Object.keys(a))

// получить все значения
console.log(Object.values(a))
```

Вам необхдимо выяснить тип данных и от этого отталкиваться

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно понял, что Вы имели ввиду таким форматом выходных данных:

```
[{тут ключи key1}, {тут ключи key2}]
```

, т.к. объекты не могут содержать только ключи - у каждого ключа долно быть значение (о коих Вы умалчиваете). Поэтому привожу пример массива ключей, значений и объектов.

```js
const obj = {
  key1: {
    'abc': 0,
    'def': true,
    'ghi': 42,
    'jkl': { 'i': 'am', 'simple': 'object' }
  },
  key2: {
    '42': ':)',
    'customKey': false,
    'xyz': 1,
    'plainObject': {'a':'b', 'c': 'd' }
  }
},
keys = [],
values = [],
objects = [];

Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  keys.push(Object.keys(obj[key]));
  values.push(Object.values(obj[key]));
  objects.push(obj[key]);
});

console.log('Keys: %o', keys);
console.log('Values: %o', values);
console.log('Objects: %o', objects);
```